# How to filter subset of nested Regex for matching groups

Tags: regex, regex-group

I am trying to figure a regex pattern to return all characters except spaces between the two special character(;). 
Thank you for your help.

Here is my regex pattern. `[^\w](?<Group1>[^;\W].+)`

Sample text to match against. 
`Please; help;me`

I was getting `help;me` as Group1 matcher but i need just `help`.

Comment: Which language are you using? What should be the result for `Please; help;me ;now`?

Comment: You need `;\s*(?<Group1>[^\s;]+)\s*;`

Comment: @ctwheels My expected output for `Please; help;me ;now` should also be
`help`. I need `Group1` to return beteen first and second semicolon.

Comment: @siddhuKantipudi what language are you using?

Comment: I am trying to run this query against splunk raw data(bigger picture was to get parse User Agent). I know Javascript has helpers methods `match` and `regex.exec` to work with but i cannot use that in my Splunk query. Sorry for not providing the context

Comment: @siddhuKantipudi revo's regex works just fine for what you're trying to do

Comment: Yes it works. Thank you @revo.

Comment: @siddhuKantipudi If you can trim the result later, you do not need  to match `\s*`. Use `;(?<Group1>[^\s;]+);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[^\w](?<Group1>[^;\W].+)` pattern matches a non-word char, then captures any char other than a non-word and `;` (i.e. any word char except `;` - which makes little sense, `;` can be safely removed from the class) and then any 1+ chars as many as possible into Group 1. Basically, it can be re-written as `\W(?<Group1>\w.+)`, and you see it matches too much and not what you need.

You may use a pattern [like this](https://regex101.com/r/mVTOpR/1), where `\S*?` matches any 0+ chars other than whitespace, as few as possible:

```
;\s*(?<Group1>\S*?)\s*;
```

Or, a more efficient variation of this pattern:

```
;\s*(?<Group1>[^;\s]*)\s*;
```

In the `[^;\s]*` pattern, the `;` is "subtracted from `\S` and `[^;\s]*` now matches zero or more chars other than whitespace and `;`, as many as possible.

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mVTOpR/2).